# Export mysql db to .csv/excel file

Tags: php, html

I have looked at many options, but nothing is working (probably because I don't know what I am doing). How can I

> export a table from MYSQL Database to an excel .csv

file onclick of an "A" tag? Actual full code would be appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://lysergicstudio.com/export-mysql-to-csv-files-with-php/) for source code (there are actually many resources on the Internet).Then, just point your href to this script.

Comment: how would I cause that to be exported via the a tag

Comment: that is really nice and works great, but how can I separate the fields in my table to seperate fields in the csv file?

Comment: there are two options: you can create a view by selecting appropriate columns from your table and naming them as you want and then instead outputting a table, make csv output of that view. Another options is to slightly modify given script, and instead of doing "select * ..." select columns you want and then instead of doing "show columns from ..." manually add your list of columns.

Comment: i tried to manually add my list of columns but then it breaks. I apologize, this is something I have never attempted before and I am still relatively new to php. Would you mind rewriting the script me so that it works? Thanks so much...:)

Comment: if you are not skilled in php, then just use Create view (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) and export data from view.

Comment: Nice, I'll look into it, but I think I may have come up with my own solution. I'll post when it is done. Thanks